# How to get some specific real-time data from several websites continuously using Python (Django)?

Tags: python, django, database, web-scraping, real-time-data

I am working on a web application that needs to pull data from other websites continuously. For example, the price of a product. 
If the price changes on the original website, my site's price will also be changed automatically.

**Is it possible to scrape/pull/get data from other websites continuously like this?**

Comment: you can't directly fetch the data from other websites, use their API.

Comment: @PankajSharma Is it illegal to do or it's not entirely possible to do? Is it possible to fetch some specific data using URL parse?

Answer (score -1):

you can write a background job to fetch data from remote host every hour/minutes/... then update your data if changed.